# Selecting the value of specific element with the same class as others

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <body>
        <div class = "element">
            Monday - <button class= "delete_button">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class = "element">
            Tuesday - <button class= "delete_button">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class = "element">
            Wednesday - <button class= "delete_button">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

For that HTML I have a JavaScript file with function with `onclick` event listener for `class= "delete_button"` and the goal is to get in JavaScript variable the value of the specific div in which is the button that has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

With the JS function parentElement and split you can do it as well.

```js
function deleteThis (e) {
  const v = e.parentElement.innerText.split('-')
  console.log('The value from div is: ', v[0])
  alert(v[0])
}
```

```html
  <body>
        <div class = "element">
            Monday - <button class= "delete_button" onclick="deleteThis(this)">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class = "element">
            Tuesday - <button onclick="deleteThis(this)" class= "delete_button">Delete</button>
        </div>
        <div class = "element">
            Wednesday - <button onclick="deleteThis(this)" class= "delete_button">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </body>
```

**small note** Try to avoid to use the onclick element. Better  to bind the buttons to a EventListener..